# How can I display which fields still need to be filled in using ASP.NET and C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, requiredfieldvalidator, required-field

I'm currently working on a web form in Visual Studio 2010 using C# and ASP.NET. It's a simple form - an online application - with several required fields. I already have regular expressions and required field validators in place, which display red asterisks when a field is left blank, but they're relatively hard to see.

Our users are a bunch of cowboys and ranch hands, so they'll just keep clicking 'Continue' if they don't immediately see what they're missing.

Is there a way to print at the bottom of the page which fields are missing?

Thanks in advance,
Ellie

Comment: Rope in the cowboys!  Whoo haaa! (slaps on a tie-down. throws hands in air)

Comment: Instead of an asterisk, you could have a gif of a riderless horse?

Comment: While I like both of these ideas, I can't say I could get away with it. I'm afraid my boss would like a list of what's missing. Next time, though.... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the ValidationSummary contol right above the buttons at the end of the form.

[Introduction to the ValidationSummary Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9h59855%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I was thinking the same. Provided he is using MVC3 or at least the fluent validation.

Comment: @VishalKumar ValidationSummary can also be used in WebForms